# On smoothness of functions on domains

Tags: real-analysis

This may be a  little bit technical question.

Let $D$ be a bounded smooth domain. Let $\nu$ denote the outer unit normal on the boundary $\partial D$ of $D$. For $\delta>0$, we consider a map defined by
\begin{align*}
\partial D \ni x \mapsto x-\delta \nu(x).
\end{align*}
One can show that there exists $C>0$ such that for any $0 <\delta \le C$, the map  $x \mapsto x-\delta \nu(x)$ is a one-to-one continuous map from $\partial D$ to the hyper surface $\{x-\delta \nu(x) \mid x \in \partial D\}$ with a continuous inverse. This shows that any point in $\overline{D}_{\delta}=\{x \in\overline{D} \mid \text{dist}(x,\partial D) \le \delta\}$ can be parametrized by $(x',r)$, where $x' \in \partial D$ and $0 \le r \le \delta$.

By using this  parameterization, we consider a smooth function whose gradient is the outward unit normal on $\partial D$. One of the candidates is as follows.

Fix $\delta$ with $0<\delta <C$, we define function $\varphi$ by
\begin{align*}
\varphi(r)=
\begin{cases}
0,\quad &r\ge \delta,\\
(1/2)(\delta-r)^2,\quad &0\le r \le \delta.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
We also define $f_\delta$ by
\begin{align*}
f_\delta(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,\quad &x \in \overline{D}\setminus \overline{D}_{\delta} ,\\
\varphi(r),\quad &x=(x',r) \in \overline{D}_{\delta} .
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

The gradient $\nabla f_\delta(x)$ should be  equal to $-\delta \nu(x)$, $x \in \partial D$.

But how do we prove that $ f_\delta$ is smooth? It seems to be correct. If $D$ has $C^3$ boundary, $f_\delta$ is twice differentiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps counterintuitively, $f_\delta$ will be *as smooth as* $\partial D$, not one derivative worse. Below, $k \geq 2$.

This can be seen by using the inverse function theorem. Indeed, let $\psi : \partial D \times (- \delta, \delta) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be given by $\psi(x, t) = x - t \nu(x)$. Assume that $\partial D$ is $C^k$. Then clearly $\nu(x)$ is $C^{k-1}$, and so $\psi$ is a $C^{k-1}$ function. We can compute its derivative at a point $(x, 0)  \in \partial D \times (- \delta, \delta)$, for example by choosing a basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $e_n = \nu(x)$, and using $e_1, \ldots, e_{n-1}$ as a basis for the tangent space $T_x\partial D$. Then $\partial_{e_i}\psi(x, 0) = e_i - 0 \cdot \partial_{e_i} \nu(x) = e_i$ when $i < n$, and $\partial_t\psi(x, 0) = - e_n$. This is clearly invertible, so by the inverse function theorem $\psi$ is a $C^{k-1}$ diffeomorphism (and in particular has a $C^{k-1}$ inverse) for small enough $\delta$.

If $t(y) : \text{Im}(\psi) \rightarrow (-\delta, \delta)$ is the $n$-th component of the inverse of $\psi$ (i.e. $r$ in your notation), this implies that $t \in C^{k-1}$. It turns out we can say more: if $x(y)$ is the $\partial D$ component of the inverse of $\psi$, this is also $C^{k-1}$, and we know that $y = x(y) - t(y) \nu(x(y))$, so taking an inner product, $t(y) = (x(y) - y) \cdot \nu(x(y))$. Differentiating in the $\nu = \nu(x(y))$ direction does not change $x(y)$, which leads to $\nabla t(y) \cdot \nu = - 1$. On the other hand, you can check that $|t(y)| = d(y, \partial D)$ directly. This implies that
$$
|t(y)| = |x(y) - y|\leq |x(y') - y|\leq |t(y')| + |y - y'|,
$$
so $|t|$ has Lipschitz constant at most $1$. This means that $\nabla t(y) = - \nu(x(y))$. [This fact is not surprising if you draw a picture, and you can check it in other ways]. But wait: $\nu(x(y))$ is the composition of a function we know is $C^{k-1}$ and a function we have already shown is $C^{k-1}$, so $\nabla t$ is $C^{k-1}$ and $t$ is $C^k$.

Finally you can compose with your function $\varphi$ and use the chain rule to conclude the same for $f_\delta$ (for $r < \delta$ if $k > 2$; otherwise use a smoother $\varphi$, etc.)

I learned of this argument from an appendix in Gilbarg, Trudinger, *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order*, but I imagine it is considered standard by geometers.